# OPENXML - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

My Sp reading XML file data with help of OPENXML in SQL Server.

There is slight problem in this. Here is xml file part

```
<Name_Address> 
    <name>JCB SALES PVT</name>
    <address>24, SALAROURIA ARENA ADUGODI</address>
    <address>HOSUR MAIN ROAD, Honolulu</address>
    <country>N</country>
</Name_Address>
```

and my SQL query is

```
SELECT 
   @address = CONVERT(VARCHAR(150), [TEXT]) 
FROM OPENXML(@idoc,'/Name_Address/address', 0) 
WHERE [text] IS NOT NULL
```

In @address I am getting last address tag value i.e

```
HOSUR MAIN ROAD, Honolulu
```

But it should be

```
24, SALAROURIA ARENA ADUGODI, HOSUR MAIN ROAD, Honolulu
```

How can I achieve this ?

Help me, guide me to do this.

regards

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server are you using??

Comment: Well worded question, and in answering I learned something. +1

Comment: Where are you getting this horrific XML from? Can you push back to whoever is supplying it for them to supply something more sane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't specifically to do to with OPENXML.

Your query...

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(150), [TEXT]) 
FROM OPENXML(@idoc,'/Name_Address/address', 0) 
WHERE [text] IS NOT NULL
```

...returns multiple rows. So when you assign to a variable, it just takes the last of the returned rows.

I've set up an example which uses a cursor to iterate through this. It includes your example document. You can paste this directly in Query Analyser (2000)/Management Studio (2005+) and it will run. all you have to do is add in your commas and spaces (I've just used a space).

```
DECLARE @hdoc int
DECLARE @doc varchar(1000)
DECLARE @address varchar(150)
DECLARE @thisaddress varchar(150)
set @address = ''
SET @doc ='
<Name_Address> 
    <name>JCB SALES PVT</name>
    <address>24, SALAROURIA ARENA ADUGODI</address>
    <address>HOSUR MAIN ROAD, Honolulu</address>
    <country>N</country>
</Name_Address>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @doc

DECLARE addr_cursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(150), [TEXT]) 
    FROM OPENXML(@hdoc,'/Name_Address/address', 0) 
    WHERE [text] IS NOT NULL

--select @@FETCH_STATUS
OPEN addr_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM addr_cursor INTO @thisaddress

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    set @address = @address+ @thisaddress + ' '
    FETCH NEXT FROM addr_cursor INTO @thisaddress
END

select @address

CLOSE addr_cursor
DEALLOCATE addr_cursor

exec sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

Comment: it works. How you came to know about this. what i want to know How can a person increase his skills and programming ability?

If you can guide me, the best way of Self Help?

Comment: @Humdum - Could you mark this as accepted by clicking on the tick. Very difficult to answer your skill/ability question. Experience and an inquisitive mind helps. For example, I hadn't even heard of OPENXML on SQL Server, but I looked it up and wrote a quick example. I decided to see what would happen if I did a select, instead of an assignment on your original `SELECT @address=....` statement. That revealed both rows were being returned, so I inferred that only the last was being set. There is much more about experience, etc here on StackOverflow, and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.